# Java BigInteger OR function

Tags: java, if-statement, biginteger

I am using Java and have some problems.
I made two BigInteger variables, p and q.
In my code, I want to add if function, like if(p=1 \ q=1).
I tried many ways but there was error. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What did you try? What was the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but you need to use the [`BigInteger.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method, as in this example:

```
if (BigInteger.equals(p, BigInteger.ONE) || BigInteger.equals(q, BigInteger.ONE)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was what I wanted :)

Comment: @HeWonCho: Please mark it as "accepted" if it answers your question.